# Earth's rotation axis orientation in space in relation to vernal equinox point

Tags: astronomy, solar-system

Lately I got confused about how the Earth's rotational axis is oriented during the vernal equinox, as I got information that Earth has an equator ascending node equal to about 11°.

If, this day, we make a plane that contains the Earth's axis and orient it so it is perpendicular to the Earth's orbital plane (Ecliptic?), will its "up" vector be pointing at the Sun? Or, to be more exact, at the 0 RA (right ascension) and 0 dec (declination) coordinates on the celestial sphere?

I think it should be "by definition", but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:**

Maybe I'll explain it with a picture:

[image: angles]

I know the green angle, but I'm more interested in the red angle. When I wrote "by definition" I mean the purple vector should be pointing at both the Sun and the vernal equinox point. Also, if I understand this right, the red angle should then be equal to 90°.

*However* if it is true the Earth's **equator** ascending node is equal to 11° then it means the red angle is not a perfect 90°. I wrote in the title "axis orientation", because to specify the Earth's rotation axis you have to provide *both* the green and the red angle value.

Comment: Earth's rotational axis is always oriented the same, due to conservation of angular momentum, and always points to the celestial poles (you know, near Polaris)... So, are you sure your question is about what your title is about?

Comment: @rfl you are right, I was not being clear in the title

Comment: The Earth's axis is tilted by about 23.4° relative to the ecliptic.  Please read this page and then update your question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt

Comment: @Dan to the ecliptic yes, but I'm also interested in how it is tilted relative to the *Sun* too. I don't know how I should update my question because I think I made myself clear enough. Probably an image would be helpful, but right now I can't make one

Comment: @Felix.leg the red angle isn't fixed, as earth goes around the sun.